# In D3.js, how do you cross-connect children in a collapsible force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We have been trying to build a collapsible force layout based on [this example in the D3.js gallery](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html).

However, our data is a graph, not a tree. For instance:

```
root = {
  "name": "adam",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "barbara",
      "children" : [
          { "name" : "carl" }
      ]
    },
    {
     "name": "diane",
    },
    {
     "name": "edward"
    }
   ]
  };

 // name * name * [node] -> { source : node, target : node}
 function crossLink(fst, snd, nodes) {
   var fstNode = nodes.filter(function (n) { return n.name === fst; })[0];
   var sndNode = nodes.filter(function (n) { return n.name === snd })[0];
   return { "source" : fstNode, "target" : sndNode };
 }

function buildGraph() {
  //flatten() is from Bostock's original, returns all nodes
  var nodes = flatten(root); 
  //Encode the tree-like aspect of the data
  var links = [
         crossLink("adam", "barbara", nodes),
         crossLink("barbara", "carl", nodes),
         crossLink("adam", "diane", nodes),
         crossLink("adam", "edward", nodes),
      ];

      //Cross-links amongst children
      //(These don't appear if a child is already linked to by a parent)
      links.push(crossLink("barbara", "diane", nodes));
      links.push(crossLink("diane", "edward", nodes));
      links.push(crossLink("diane", "carl", nodes));
      ...etc...
```

The result shows the "tree-like" links as expected, but not the desired "cross-links amongst children":

[image]

*But* if I delete, e.g., the "tree-like" link "barbara-carl", the "diane-carl" link appears.

It is clearly possible to build a force-layout that uses a graph, but I've gotten cross-eyed trying to figure out where we are going wrong. (Another thought is that I'm making the mistake at a different area of the code, but I didn't want to post the whole program and say "can someone debug this?")

Comment: In principle, you just need to add the appropriate data for the links. For a collapsible layout this is more difficult though as you would need to add/remove links as groups are expanded/collapsed.

Comment: Perhaps the data structure being used does not help. Would not the structure in graph.json [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500) be more suitable?